# How can i add custom boxes and texts to a website using JS extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i want to know how can i add a custom box for example that has a text in it on a website using javascript extension. this is how it should work: when you load unpacked extension on chrome and go on a specific website you choose to add things onto (for example stack overflow). i want to add custom html and css to the website like: a custom button, a text, a box etc..

i currently don't have any idea of what i can do. any kind of help will be appreciated a lot.

i don't have any code.

Comment: Using  a *userscript* in extensions like Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey is the easiest approach

Comment: can it be done by using the javascript extension?

Comment: Those ***are*** extensions for running javascript and a *userscript* is written in javascript. Not hard to find tutorials on how to implement them